# How could I show that if $a$ is an integer, then $a^3 \equiv 1, 0, 6 \mod 7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, modular-arithmetic

I've literally tried everything including proofs by cases. If I were to try a an odd integer, then I would get $8k^3 + 4k^2 + 8k^2 + 4k + 1$, which obviously couldn't convert to a $\mod 7$, and I'm honestly not sure what I can do! Does anyone here have any tips?

Note, this is a soft question.

Comment: Hint: you need to check only for $a=0, \pm1,\pm2, \pm3$.

Comment: Every $a$ is $7k$ or $7k+1$, or $\dots$ or $7k+6$ for some $k$. Better: every number $a$ is $7k$, $7k\pm 1$, $7k\pm 2$, or $7k\pm 3$. Calculate, one case at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to do this: I'll present the bashy casework method, mostly because it's often the first one that comes to mind.  I know there are better ways to do this, but this is what you probably should immediately think to try.

If $a \equiv 0 \bmod 7$, $a^3 \equiv 0 \bmod 7$.

If $a \equiv 1 \bmod 7$, $a^3 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$.

If $a \equiv 2 \bmod 7$, $a^3 \equiv 8 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$.

If $a \equiv 3 \bmod 7$, $a^3 \equiv 27 \equiv 6 \bmod 7$.

If $a \equiv 4 \equiv -3 \bmod 7$, $a^3 \equiv -6 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$.

If $a \equiv 5 \equiv -2 \bmod 7$, $a^3 \equiv -1 \equiv 6 \bmod 7$.

If $a \equiv 6 \equiv -1 \bmod 7$, $a^3 \equiv -1 \equiv 6 \bmod 7$.

Note that this covers all the bases since an integer $a$ can only take on these $7$ values $\bmod \ 7$.  Thus we're done.

Answer (score 3):

Any integer $a$ can be written as one of the following : $a= 7m, 7m+1,7m+2,7m+3,7m+4,7m+5,7m+6$, for some integer $m$.

The cubic residues of each (and therefore all possible cubic residues) modulo $7$ is then  $0,1^3,2^3,3^3,4^3,5^3,6^3$.

For easier computation, you can rewrite the$7m+4,7m+5,7m+6$ as $7m-3,7m-2,7m-1$ since they are equivalent modulo 7.

Comment: Can I ask what part of the theory of modular arithmetic allows you to conclude this?

Comment: All integers can be written in one of the above forms. If you consider the cubic residues of each form modulo 7, you find that $a \equiv 0^3,1^3,...,6^3 \mod 7$. This is because $(7m + k)^ 7 \equiv k^7$ for integers $m,k$, a property of modular congruences which can be and has been proved.

Comment: @Matthew because _every_ number can represented as above. Also tip: do $7m-1$ instead of $7m+6$. and so on.